# PHP array into Javascript Array

Tags: php, javascript, while-loop

Afternoon all. The code below works perfectly, however, I need to pull each row of the php sql array out and into the script var. Any ideas on how to write a while loop that could do this? Thanks for any help

```
 var enableDays = ["<?php echo mysql_result($result, 0, 'date'); ?>"];

 enableDays.push("<?php echo mysql_result($result, 1, 'date'); ?>");
```

Additional Code::

```
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}



    var enableDays = [<?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>];

    console.log(enableDays[1]);
```

Comment: I'm curious why you wouldn't just use PHP to write a "service" that returns JSON and call it using Ajax methods in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the rows using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and then encode it to JSON:

```
<?php
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
?>


var enableDays = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
```

Comment: You'll probably want to remove the outer `[]`, `json_encode` already churns out a valid JS object literal, why bother wrapping it in a pointless array?

Comment: When I do this, and then use console.log(enableDays[1]); To check it, I just says 'undefined' any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: Are you using `mysqli`?

Comment: If I don't want an associative array returned, but rather a numerically indexed one, how would I do that? Thanks

Comment: You can use `mysqli_fetch_row`

Comment: Thanks mate, you have been really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Pull your data out into a PHP array, then transfer that to JavaScript with

```
var enableDays = <?php echo json_encode($enableDays); ?>;
```

As an aside, the obligatory recommendation that you should stop using the PHP `mysql` extension immediately because it is not very safe and has been deprecated; switch to something better (`mysqli` and `PDO` are both good choices).

Comment: I've tried that, and then when I do a console.log($enableDays[1]); It says undefined. How would you pull it into a php array?

Comment: @user2014175: You did not try *that*, because it would have worked. You tried something *similar*; show us what it was.

Comment: @user2014175 This answer is better than mine. If it's not working for you, try logging the json to your PHP logfile to find out whether you're really producing the entire array correctly.

Comment: @user2014175 I mean log to your PHP logfile, not console.log. Use error_log($rows) and error_log(json_encode($rows));

Comment: @user2014175: That's jh314's code from their answer, and it has extra brackets around the `<?php ?>` tags which is wrong (that answer has been since edited to correct this).

Answer (score 1):

This can't work. Once the page is loaded, all the PHP has run already. But if you're really just adding the next mysql_result for each push, you could have PHP create the entire enableDays array for you:

```
<?php
  echo 'var enableDays = ["' . mysql_result(...) . '", "' . mysql_result(...) . '"];'
?>
```

Comment: What if one of the results contains a double quote? What if it ends with a slash? Don't encode manually -- that's what `json_encode` is for.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help

```
  <?php 
    $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
    foreach($res as $key => $val){ ?>
            enableDays.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
    <?php } 
  ?>
```